# Pyignite Client.connect failed: Connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, databricks, ignite

Azure

- vNet address: 10.106.0.0/15
- databricks public subnet address prefix: 10.106.3.0/24
- databricks private subnet address prefix: 10.106.4.0/24
- Databricks Runtime 7.4 (Apache Spark 3.0.1) deployed with delegated subnets
- Kubernetes subnet address prefix: 10.106.8.0/22
- Kubernetes version 1.19.7
- Apache Ignite 2.9.1 deployed in the cabernets

```
$ kubectl get svc -n ayushman
NAME TYPE CLUSTER-IP EXTERNAL-IP PORT(S) AGE
cohort store Load Balancer 10.0.163.252 10.106.8.255 8080:31751/TCP,10800:30608/TCP,10900:31092/TCP 29h
```

We are getting 'Connection refused' error when trying to connect to Apache Ignite cluster from Databricks Notebooks. Below is our simple code snippet.

```py
from pyignite import Client
client = Client(timeout=40.0)
client.connect('10.106.8.255', 10900)
```

We are able to connect to Apache Ignite using `./sqlline.sh` from another Linux machine with in the vNet (outside the K8S subnet)

Any help to resolve this issues?

Comment: Are you sure that 10900 is the correct port? By default, thin clients connect to 10800. I'm also not sure I understand how to read your k8s readout correctly. Is internal port 10800 mapped to 30608 externally? If so, shouldn't you connect to 30608?

Comment: K8S readout details Cluster IP: 10.0.163.252 Internal LB IP: 10.106.8.255. My successful ./sqlline.sh connection details.
azureuser@devjumpbox:~/apache-ignite-2.9.1-bin/bin$ ./sqlline.sh -u "jdbc:ignite:thin://10.106.8.255:10800"
issuing: !connect jdbc:ignite:thin://10.106.8.255:10800 '' '' org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver
Connecting to jdbc:ignite:thin://10.106.8.255:10800
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
sqlline version 1.3.0
0: jdbc:ignite:thin://10.106.8.255:10800>

Comment: My both attempts failed client.connect('10.106.8.255', 10900) and client.connect('10.106.8.255', 10800)

Comment: My Ignite helm charts are here https://github.com/sunkararp/IgniteCharts

Comment: @StephenDarlington Nodeport:30608  port:10800 targetport:10800 Nodeport:31092 port:10900 targetport:10900